# 403 RXJS error when trying to subscribe to websocket | Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, websocket

I'm trying to find a solution for this without upgrading angular or dependencies as it might affect rest of the code base

[image]

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "angular4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation for visual studio 2017 & WebApi",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "dev-build": "gulp dev-build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "3.7.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "3.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "3.5.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "3.14.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "4.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "3.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.5.11",
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "0.2.5",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.46.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
    "jszip": "3.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.15",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

[image]

search.component.ts

```html
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { WebSocketSubject } from "rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject";
import { webSocket } from "rxjs/observable/dom/webSocket";
   public openWebSocket = async (uniqueId: string) => {
    const url: string = this.commonService.wssurl + '/api/ABCWebSocket/' + uniqueId;
    let socket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket(url);
    console.log('socketsub = ' + WebSocketSubject.webSocket);
    console.log('url ' + url);

    let onWebSocketResponse = new Subject<any>();
    onWebSocketResponse.subscribe(async (socketRes) => {
        if (socketRes !== "NULL") {
            console.log("message received with :" + uniqueId);
        } else {

        }
    });

    this.subscribeToWebSocket(
        socket,
        uniqueId,
        onWebSocketResponse
    );
  };
```

code snippet causing the error - Guess the Subscribe part throws the error as when commenting it out it works fine
[image]

The backend is a .Net project btw. Went through few answer in few forums but did not get what I expect as am not trying to update the packages

Comment: Why you add async in the subscription callback ? That line is causing the error. RxJs has native support for websockets why you are creating your own wrapper?

Comment: @onrails tried removing and running the async, still the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a constraint that pushes you create your own wrapper around `websockets` with `RxJs`, `RxJs` has its own a native solution for `websockets`.
This wrapper supports:

1- Listening

2- Pushing

3- Multiplexing

Here is an example of an `RxJs` websocket to listen to server

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

subject.subscribe({
  next: msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg), // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
  error: err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
  complete: () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Update... - as I think it might help someone, the issue was due to old Angular 5 used and the way I tried to subscribe to the websocket does not support. Below is the way to subscribe via observable

```
this.url = this.commonVariables.wssurl + '/api/AbcApi/' + id;
    this.wsService.createObservableSocket(this.url)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                //TODO After received Response
                console.log('message from server with id: ' + data);
                this.UpdateUi(data);
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('The observable stream is complete')
    );
```

and in websocket.service class

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
```

export class WebSocketService {
ws: WebSocket;

```
createObservableSocket(url: string): Observable<string> {
    console.log('created observable socket');
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.ws.onmessage = (event) => observer.next(event.data);
        this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
        this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    });
}
sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.ws.send(message);
}
```

}